# How to execute benchmarks in Rust Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm looking at a rust crate [`rust-crypto`](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto) right now. There are multiple tests with a bench attribute. When I execute cargo bench, I don't get any benchmark results, it just says all the tests are ignored.

When I google for this I can't find anything. The documentation of the crate also doesn't say how to use these benchmarks.

What would I need to do to execute, e.g. the MD5 benchmarks?

Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Please comment why you downvote my question? I've stated my problem precisely, I couldn't find a duplicate question using Google or Stackoverflow search. I also couldn't find this in the official docs or the docs of the crate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crate uses [a feature](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/cc1a5fde1ce957bd1a8a2e30169443cdb4780111/Cargo.toml) to enable or disable this benchmarks. [By default they are disabled.](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/master/src/md5.rs#L291)
To execute benchmarks, you have to explicitly ask for it:

```
cargo bench --features=with-bench
```

Which for me results with

```
test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 115 ignored; 67 measured; 0 filtered out
```

The 115 ignored tests are not bench tests.

If you wish to only run MD5 benchmarks, you can use

```
cargo bench --features=with-bench -- md5
```

Which results with

```
test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 4 ignored; 3 measured; 175 filtered out
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find this in the official documentation anywhere!